# Read/extract data from sql server backup file without restoring

Tags: c#, sql-server, visual-c++

Is there any way to read/extract data from sql server backup file without restoring it?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Idera have recently released a product - which sounds fantastic - that allows you to do just this. I've never used it, but it's top of my list of things to try!!!!

http://www.idera.com/Products/SQL-toolbox/SQL-virtual-database/

Comment: Yes, it's a third party add-on - but it integrates fully with SQL Server, and allows you to do things that are not possible natively with SQL Server. It's very attractive to DBAs, probably not to developers.

Answer (score 0):

Actually it is not such a bad idea to attach a backup and read in vs restoring it.
I found this discussion interesting - http://www.codeproject.com/Questions/58905/Read-sql-server-backup-files-without-restoring